How to get/determine the Green's Function?
I want to determine the Green's function of $$t y^{\prime \prime}(t)+y^{\prime}(t)=t, \quad y(1)=y(e)=0.$$
I have even solved the ODE with the initial conditions, but I do not know how to determine the Green's function:
We have a second-order linear ODE.
Let $$\frac{dy(t)}{dt} = v(t),$$ which gives $$\frac{d^{2}y(t)}{dt^{2}} = \frac{dv(t)}{dt}.$$
Now, substitute $1 = \frac{d}{dt}(t):$
$$t \cdot \frac{dv(t)}{dt}+\frac{d}{dt}(t)v(t) = t.$$
I apply the reverse product rule:
$$\frac{dg}{dt}f+\frac{df}{dt}g=\frac{d}{dt}fg$$
to the left hand side:
$$\frac{d}{dt}(tv(t))=t.$$
Then, I integrate both sides with respect to $t:$
$$\int \frac{d}{dt}(tv(t))dt=\int t dt \implies tv(t)=\frac{t^{2}}{2}+c_{1} \implies v(t)=\frac{t}{2}+\frac{c_{1}}{t}.$$
Now, I have to substitute back:
$$\frac{dy(t)}{dt}=\frac{t}{2t}+\frac{c_{1}}{t}$$
Then, I integrate both sides with respect to $t:$
$$y(t) = \int \left(\frac{t}{2t}+\frac{c_{1}}{t}\right) dt = \frac{t^{2}}{4} + c_{1} \cdot \ln(t) + c_{2}.$$
We have the following initial conditions:
$$y(1)=0$$
$$y(e)=0$$
So, we substitute and obtain $$c_{1}=\frac{1}{4} \cdot (1-e^{2})$$ and $$c_2=-\frac{1}{4},$$ so substituting in $y(t)$ I get:
$$y(t) = \frac{1}{4}(t^{2}+\ln(t)-e^{2} \cdot \ln(t) -1)$$
Could anyone help me, please? Thank you very much in advance <3

$y_1 = 1$, $y_2 = \ln t$, $G(x, t) = \frac{y_1(t)y_2(x) - y_1(x) y_2(t)}{W}$, $W = W[y_1, y_2]$ is the Wronskian.

The Green's function $G(t,t')$ is the solution to
$$
\left(t\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}+\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)G(t,t')
=\delta(t-t') \qquad (1<t'<e),
$$
$$
G(1,t')=G(e,t')=0.
$$

How do you obtain $y_1$ and $y_2$? @Yimin

they are the solutions to your equation with RHS = 0. @BarbaraMaría, you solve that using Cauchy-Euler equation's techniques.

First, we need to find two solutions to the associated homogeneous equation which satisfy the boundary conditions.
Given: $$ t \frac{d^2 y(t)}{dt^2} + \frac{dy(t)}{dt} = 0$$
Let $\frac{dy(t)}{dt} = v(t)$, which gives $$\frac{d^2 y(t)}{dt^2} = \frac{dv(t)}{dt}$$
Then, we solve for $\frac{dv(t)}{dt}$: $$ \frac{dv(t)}{dt} = -\frac{v(t)}{t}$$
We divide both sides by $v(t)$: $$ \frac{\frac{dv(t)}{dt}}{v(t)} = -\frac{1}{t}$$
After that, we integrate both sides with respect to $t$: $$ \int \frac{\frac{dv(t)}{dt}}{v(t)} dt = \int -\frac{1}{t} dt \implies  \log(v(t)) = -\log(t) + c_1,$$
where $c_1$ is an arbitrary constant.
Now, we solve for $v(t)$: $$ v(t) = e^{c_1}/t$$
We should simplify the arbitrary constant: $$ v(t) = c_1/t$$
We substitute back for $\frac{dy(t)}{dt} = v(t)$: $$ \frac{dy(t)}{dt} = c_1/t$$
After that, we integrate both sides with respect to $t$: $$ y(t) = \int c_1/t \quad dt = c_1 \log(t) + c_2,$$
where $c_2$ is an arbitrary constant.
I will take:
\begin{align}
    y_1(t) &= c_1 \log(t) + c_2 \tag{1} \\
    y_2(t) &= c_3 \log(t) + c_4 \tag{2}
\end{align}
I will force $(1)$ to meet the first boundary condition by choosing appropriate constants and I will force $(2)$ to meet the second boundary condition by choosing appropriate constants.
The first condition is $y(1)=0$ so, $y_1(1)=0$:
$$0 = c_1 \log(1) + c_2 \implies 0 = c_2.$$
So, I must take $c_2 = 0$, and for ease of use, I am going to take $c_1 = 1$.
Then,
$$y_1(t) = \log(t). \tag{3}$$
The second condition is $y(e)=0$ so, $y_2(e)=0$:
$$0 = c_3\log(e)+c_4 \implies 0 = c_3 + c_4.$$
So, for ease of use, I am going to take $c_3=-1$ and $c_4=1$.
Then,
$$y_2(t)=1-\log(t). \tag{4}$$
Secondly, Green's function is defined for the standard form, leading term is normalized:
$$G'' + \frac{1}{t}G' = \delta(t - s)$$
with boundary values $G(a, s) = G(b, s) = 0$.
By applying the variation of parameters to the equation of G (here regarding s as a fixed thing),
$$G(t, s) = y_1(t)\int_t^b \frac{y_2(z) \delta(z-s)}{W(z)} dz + y_2(t)\int_a^t \frac{y_1(z)\delta(z-s)}{W(z)} dz = \begin{cases} \frac{y_1(s) y_2(t)}{W(s)} ,\quad t\ge s \\
    \frac{y_1(t) y_2(s)}{W(s)},\quad s\ge t \end{cases}$$
Here the boundary values $G(a, s) = 0$ means $y_1(a) = 0$ and $G(b, s)=0$ means $y_2(b) = 0$.
Moreover, we have to calculate the Wronskian using $(3)$ and $(4)$:
$$W(y_1, y_2)(t) = \det
\begin{pmatrix}
y_1(t) & y_2(t) \\
y_1^{\prime}(t) & y_2^{\prime}(t)
\end{pmatrix}
= \det
\begin{pmatrix}
\log(t) & 1-\log(t) \\
1/t & -1/t
\end{pmatrix}
= -1/t$$
Now, the Wronskian is evaluated at $t = s$:
$$W(s)=-\frac{1}{s}$$
Then,
$$G(t, s) = \begin{cases} s(-\log(s)+\log(s)\log(t)) ,\quad t\ge s \\
s(-\log(t)+\log(t)\log(s)),\quad s\ge t \end{cases}$$

@Yimin is it correct now?

What do you think, Gonçalo?

Your solution is correct, but a remark is in order here. The way I defined the Green's function (see my comment below the question), the solution to the original ODE is given by $y(t)=\int_1^eG(t,s)s,ds$, whereas in the convention adopted by Yimin (and you) it is given by $y(t)=\int_1^eG(t,s)\frac{s}{s},ds.$

What do you think, @Átila Correia ?

Another possible approach for the sake of curiosity:
\begin{align*}
ty'' + y' = t & \Longleftrightarrow (ty')' = t\\
& \Longleftrightarrow ty' = \frac{t^{2}}{2} + A\\
& \Longleftrightarrow y' = \frac{t}{2} + \frac{A}{t}\\
& \Longleftrightarrow y(t) = \frac{t^{2}}{4} + A\ln|t| + B 
\end{align*}

(+1)  Clear and concise

I have published the solution, what do you think about it?

First, Green's function is defined for the standard form, leading term is normalized $$G'' + \frac{1}{t}G' = \delta(t - x)$$ with boundary values $G(a, x) = G(b, x) = 0$. This is slightly different from the comment by Gonçalo.
By applying the variation of parameters to the equation of $G$ (here regarding $x$ as a fixed thing),
$$G(t, x) = y_1(t)\int_t^b \frac{y_2(z) \delta(z-x)}{W(z)} dz + y_2(t)\int_a^t \frac{y_1(z)\delta(z-x)}{W(z)} dz = \begin{cases} \frac{y_1(x) y_2(t)}{W(x)} ,\quad t\ge x\\ \frac{y_1(t) y_2(x)}{W(x)},\quad x\ge t \end{cases}$$
Here the boundary values $G(a, x) = 0$ means $y_1(a) = 0$ and $G(b, x)=0$ means $y_2(b) = 0$.
In your problem, $y_1 = \ln t$ and $y_2 = 1 - \ln t$, $W(t) = -1/t$. Then solution can be written as $$\int_1^e G(t, x)dx$$

First, we need to find two solutions to the associated homogeneous equation which satisfy the boundary conditions.
\vspace{0.3cm}
\text{Given:} $$\quad  t \frac{d^2 y(t)}{dt^2} + \frac{dy(t)}{dt} = 0$$
\vspace{0.3cm}
\text{Let} $\quad \frac{dy(t)}{dt} = v(t)$, \text{ which gives } $$\frac{d^2 y(t)}{dt^2} = \frac{dv(t)}{dt}$$
\vspace{0.3cm}
\text{Then. we solve for } $\frac{dv(t)}{dt}$: $$\quad  \frac{dv(t)}{dt} = -\frac{v(t)}{t}$$
\vspace{0.3cm}
\text{We divide both sides by } $v(t)$: $$\quad  \frac{\frac{dv(t)}{dt}}{v(t)} = -\frac{1}{t}$$
\vspace{0.3cm}
\text{After that, we integrate both sides with respect to } $t$: $$\quad  \int \frac{\frac{dv(t)}{dt}}{v(t)} dt = \int -\frac{1}{t} dt \implies  \log(v(t)) = -\log(t) + c_1, \text{ where } c_1 \text{ is an arbitrary constant.}$$
\vspace{0.3cm}
\text{Now, we solve for } $v(t)$: $$\quad  v(t) = e^{c_1}/t$$
\vspace{0.3cm}
\text{We should simplify the arbitrary constant:} $$\quad  v(t) = c_1/t$$
\vspace{0.3cm}
\text{We substitute back for } $\frac{dy(t)}{dt} = v(t)$: $$\quad  \frac{dy(t)}{dt} = c_1/t$$
\vspace{0.3cm}
\text{After that, we integrate both sides with respect to } $t$: $$\quad  y(t) = \int c_1/t \quad dt = c_1 \log(t) + c_2, \text{ where } c_2 \text{ is an arbitrary constant.} $$
\vspace{0.3cm}
I will take:
\begin{center}
$y_1(t) = c_1 log(t) + c_2 \quad \quad (1)$
\vspace{0.3cm}
$y_2(t) = c_3 log(t) + c_4 \quad \quad (2)$

\end{center}
I will force (1) to meet the first boundary condition by choosing appropriate constants and I will force (2) to meet the second boundary condition by choosing appropriate constants.
\vspace{0.3cm}
The first condition is $y(1)=0$ so, $y_1(1)=0$:
\begin{center}
$0 = c_1 log(1) + c_2 \implies 0 = c_2$.
\end{center}
\vspace{0.3cm}
Then,
\begin{center}
$y_1(t) = c_1log(t)$. \quad \quad \quad $(3)$
\end{center}
\vspace{0.3cm}
The second condition is $y(e)=0$ so, $y_2(e)=0$:
\begin{center}
$0 = c_3log(e)+c_4 \implies 0 = c_3 + c_4 \implies c_4 = -c_3$.
\end{center}
\vspace{0.3cm}
Then,
\begin{center}
$y_2(t)=c_3log(t)-c_3 \implies y_2(t) = c_3(log(t)-1)$. \quad \quad \quad $(4)$
\end{center}
\vspace{0.3cm}
We know that:
\begin{center}
$G(t, s) = \begin{cases} d_1(s)y_1(t) ,\quad a \leq t \leq s \leq b
\vspace{0.5cm}\
d_2(s)y_2(t),\quad a \leq s \leq t \leq b \end{cases}$
\end{center}
where
\begin{center}
$d_1(s)=\frac{y_2(s)}{p(s)Wy_1,y_2}, \quad s \in [a,b]$
\vspace{0.3cm}

$d_2(s)=\frac{y_1(s)}{p(s)W[y_1,y_2](s)}, \quad s \in [a,b]$

\end{center}
\vspace{0.3cm}
Here the boundary values $G(a, s) = 0$ means $y_1(a) = 0$ and $G(b, s)=0$ means $y_2(b) = 0$.
\vspace{0.3cm}
Moreover, we have to calculate the Wronskian using $(3)$ and $(4)$:
\begin{center}
$W[y_1, y_2](t) = \det
\begin{pmatrix}
y_1(t) & y_2(t) \\
y_1^{\prime}(t) & y_2^{\prime}(t)
\end{pmatrix}
= \det
\begin{pmatrix}
c_1log(t) & c_3(log(t)-1) \\
c_1/t & c_3/t
\end{pmatrix}
= \frac{c_1c_3}{t}
$
\end{center}
Now, the Wronskian is evaluated at $t = s$:
\begin{center}
$W[y_1,y_2](s)=\frac{c_1c_3}{s}$
\end{center}
Moreover, we have $p(t) = t \implies p(s)=s$.
\vspace{0.3cm}
So,
\begin{center}
$d_1(s)=\frac{c_3(log(s)-1)}{s \frac{c_1c_3}{s}} = \frac{log(s)-1}{c_1}, \quad s \in [a,b]$
    \vspace{0.3cm}

            $d_2(s)=\frac{c_1log(s)}{s \frac{c_1c_3}{s}} = \frac{log(s)}{c_3}, \quad s \in [a,b]$

\end{center}
Then,
$$G(t, s) = \begin{cases} \frac{log(s)-1}{c_1}c_1log(t) ,\quad a \leq t \leq s \leq b
\vspace{0.5cm} \
\frac{log(s)}{c_3}c_3(log(t)-1),\quad a \leq t \leq s \leq b \end{cases} \implies $$
\vspace{0.3cm}
$$\implies G(t, s) = \begin{cases} (log(s)-1)log(t) ,\quad a \leq t \leq s \leq b
\vspace{0.5cm} \
(log(t)-1)log(s),\quad a \leq t \leq s \leq b \end{cases} $$

@Yimin better this?

Was this what you refered to, @gonçalo ?

The given differential equation is $ty''(t) + y'(t) = t$ with boundary conditions $y(1) = y(e) = 0$.
Step 1: Homogeneous Solution
First, we need to find the homogeneous solution of the differential equation. The homogeneous version of the given differential equation is $ty''(t) + y'(t) = 0$.
We look for solutions of the form $y(t) = e^{rt}$, where $r$ is a constant. Substituting this into the homogeneous equation gives a characteristic equation in terms of $r$. The roots of this equation give the exponents for the solutions of the homogeneous differential equation.
However, in this case, the homogeneous solutions are given as $y_1 = 1$ and $y_2 = \ln(t)$.
Step 2: Wronskian
Next, we calculate the Wronskian of these solutions, denoted by $W[y_1, y_2]$, which is the determinant of the matrix formed by the solutions and their derivatives. So,
\begin{align*}
W &= y_1*y_2' - y_2*y_1' \\
  &= 1*(1/t) - \ln(t)*0 \\
  &= 1/t
\end{align*}
Step 3: Green's Function
The Green's function $G(x, t)$ is defined as:
\begin{align*}
G(x, t) &= (y_1(t)y_2(x) - y_1(x)y_2(t)) / W \\
        &= (1*\ln(x) - 1*\ln(t)) / (1/t) \\
        &= t*\ln(x) - t*\ln(t)
\end{align*}
So, the Green's function for the given differential equation is $G(x, t) = t\ln(x) - t\ln(t)$. This function can be used to find the particular solution of the non-homogeneous differential equation.

Would it be like this, @Yimin ? How do I set the piecewise Green's function?

Yimin's expression for the Green's function is not correct. I suggest that you adapt to your ODE the solution given by davidllerenav for a similar problem.

I did not notice your boundary values, when you have boundary values, you have to set $y_1$ and $y_2$ to comply with each boundary value, that is $y_1 = c_1 + c_2 \ln (t) $ and $y_2(t) = c_3 +c_4 \ln (t)$ satisfies $y_1(1)  = 0$ and $y_2(e) = 0$, Then Green's function is $\frac{y_1(x) y_2(t)}{W(x)}$ for $t\ge x$ and $\frac{y_1(t) y_2(x)}{W(x)}$ for $t\le x$, the Green's function satisfies $G'' + \frac{G'}{t} = \delta(t-x)$ with given boundary values.
